# Aptana Studio MySQL Connection String using SSH

Tags: mysql, ssh, aptana

I would like to connect to a MySQL DB using SSH from Aptana Studio, does anyone know what the connection string should be?

Answer (score 1):

Try this post:
http://mysqlbarbeque.blogspot.com/2008/12/ssh-tunneling-between-databases-with.html